# Multiple spreadsheets are created when I only want one

Tags: google-sheets-api

I know this must be a simple solution, but I can't find how to do this.
Using google-api-services-sheetsv4-rev581-1.25.0.  When I do

```
             result = service
                .spreadsheets()
                .create(spreadSheet).execute();
```

If I run my app a second time, an identical spreadsheet is created.  I did not find any method to tell me "Spreadsheet.Exists".  I have tried several attempts to get this, but I have not succeeded yet.

Comment: If you want to check the duplicated file using the file name, unfortunately, it cannot be achieved using Sheets API. So how about using the method of Files: list of Drive API using the search query of name='### filename ###' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false? When the length of array of `files` is more than `0`, it means that the file is existing. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you.  I tried this before, but I always put in the driveId and that gave back a response like "shared drive is not found", so I didn't know what to do with it.  If I leave the driveId off, then it will find it by name and the other parameters you gave above.

Comment: I think I have to wait "question eligible for bounty in 23 hours".  I don't see anywhere I can mark it as an acceptable answer.

Comment: I couldn't notice about it. I apologize for this.

Comment: I still don't see a checkmark to mark it as an acceptable answer.  Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for the situation.